# What are complete sentences of elliptic phrases such as "Or being lied about..."?

Tags: ellipsis, participles, present-participles, participle-clauses, participle-phrases

> If you can wait and not be tired by waiting,
>
> Or **being** lied about, don't deal in lies,
>
> Or **being** hated, don't give way to hating,
>
> And yet don't look too good, nor talk too wise:

Is the following their complete sentence?

> If you can wait and **if you can** not be tired by waiting,
>
> Or **when you are** lied about, **and you** don't deal in lies,
>
> Or **when you are** hated, **and you** don't give way to hating,
>
> And **and** yet **you** don't look too good, nor talk too wise:

Is it correct?

Do I use wrong words?

Or is there any other correct or better answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you indicate, this text is elliptical, meaning that some words have been omitted. However, you don't need to remove any more words to get the full meaning. Here is how I'd write out these lines (with double brackets to indicate the omited words):

> If you can wait and not be tired by waiting or [[by]] being lied about, [[then]] don't deal in lies.
>
> [[If you can wait and not be tired by waiting]] or [[by]] being hated, [[then]] don't give way to hating.
>
> And yet [[you]] don't look too good nor talk too wise:

I deleted the first comma in each sentence (and included "then" in the first two sentences) to make the syntax clearer. Also, note that the last sentence would typically contain "or" instead of "nor".

Comment: Oh, what a terrific answer. I didn't think of usages of the word [by] and the repetition of a clause. Thumbs-up.

Comment: Is [[If you cannot be tired]] a full meaning for "not be tired"?

Comment: Yes, the auxiliary verb "can" has two complements: "wait" and "not be tired".